# How to convert a dict to string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Assume I have a dict:

```
{
'a':'vala',
'b':'valb',
'c':'valc'
}
```

I want to convert this to a string:

```
"a='vala' , b='valb' c='valc'"
```

What is the best way to get there? I want to do something like:

```
mystring = ""
for key in testdict:
  mystring += "{}='{}'".format(key, testdict[key]).join(',')
```

Comment: you want a comment after ```'valb'```, correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a generator expression for this. Note that a dictionary doesn't have any order, so the items will be arbitrarily ordered:

```
>>> dct = {'a':'vala', 'b':'valb'}
>>> ','.join('{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in dct.items())
"a='vala',b='valb'"
```

If you want quotes around the values regardless of their type then replace `{!r}` with `'{}'`. An example showing the difference:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 1, 'b': '2'}
>>> ','.join('{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in dct.items())
"a=1,b='2'"
>>> ','.join("{}='{}'".format(k, v) for k, v in dct.items())
"a='1',b='2'"
```

Comment: Plus1, Can you please explain what is `!r` ?

Comment: @Amit [`!r` is a conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), it will get the `repr` representation of the object, which in case of string object contains those additional single quotes OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Close! `.join` is used to join together items in an iterable by a character, so you needed to append those items to a list, then join them together by a comma at the end like so:

```
testdict ={
'a':'vala',
'b':'valb'
}
mystring = []
for key in testdict:
  mystring.append("{}='{}'".format(key, testdict[key]))

print ','.join(mystring)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use something other than a "comma" can it be a string like " concat "

Comment: @Rolando it can be any string you want it to be!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just if you want to have a sorted result:

```
d={'a':'vala', 'b':'valb', 'c':'valc'}
st = ", ".join("{}='{}'".format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items()))
print(st)
```

Result

```
a='vala', b='valb', c='valc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
" , ".join( "%s='%s'"%(key,val) for key,val in mydict.items() )
```